# ListBox in Grid not resize in SplitView

Tags: listbox, uwp

I have problem with resize gridlayout.
This is man page:
[image]

This page has ListBox in 3 column. But when I fill in the data my ListBox I don't see my buttons and scrollbar. I have ScrollBar in ScrollViewer but it doesn't work. I generate all values in For loop (100 items). For now I have something like this:

[image]

This is my code of page:

```xml
<Page
x:Class="MemoryWords.LernWords"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MemoryWords"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Name="mainPage">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                       Name="WordBeforeTranslation" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="20"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" >
            <TextBlock Name="WordAfterTranslation" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Name="WordArticulation" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="20"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2">
            <ListBox Name="AllWords"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="0"
                    Content="Previous"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="Check"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                    Content="Next"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="0"
                Name="BtnLoadFile"
                Click="BtnLoadFile_Click"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Content="Load file"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Content="New Random"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Content="--------"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

Next case:
How I can set on starting, my grid filled all content of page without loaded data to ListBox? And Can I resize my app without lost of content? I don't want set permanent values to height and width. I would like have only layouts without permanent values. Generally, I would like when I will rescale app, my grid will by have similar layout.

I would like to make my page look like as on first my screenshot. 
Is it possible?

EDIT:

This is my code from MainPage:

```
<Page
x:Class="MemoryWords.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MemoryWords"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<StackPanel>
    <CommandBar HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <AppBarButton Label="Menu" Click="ToogleMenu_Click">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE700;"/>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back" Click="GoBack_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Home" Label="Play" Click="GoHome_Click"/>
    </CommandBar>
    <!--<Button Content="Open" Click="Button_Click"/>-->
    <SplitView Name="MySplitView"
               DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"
               CompactPaneLength="50"
               OpenPaneLength="200">
        <SplitView.Pane >
            <StackPanel>
                <ListBox SelectionMode="Single"
                         Name="ListOfMenu"
                         SelectionChanged="ListOfMenu_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBoxItem Name="LearnWordsItem">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                                       Text="&#xE12B;" 
                                       FontSize="30"
                                       MinWidth="50"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Nauka słówek"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>

                    <ListBoxItem Name="SettingItem">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                                       Text="&#xE115;" 
                                       FontSize="30"
                                       MinWidth="50"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Ustawienia"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>

                </ListBox>


            </StackPanel>

        </SplitView.Pane>

        <SplitView.Content>
            <StackPanel>

                <Frame Name="MyFrame">

                </Frame>

            </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: Is this the whole code, or there is something in the code behind? Also it seems that you have some kind of menu/hamburger. When I copy paste your code to empty page it seems to work ok on my desktop. BTW: why you wrap listbox in scrollviewer, when it already has its own?

Comment: It isn't whole code, I showed only code of page. In MainView I have SplitView and my page I loaded to Frame. Why I wrap ListBox to ScrollViewer? Because scrollbar in ListBox also didn't worked.

Comment: Can you copy paste the code from your question to empty page, in click event put only `AllWords.ItemsSource = items;` where items are some dummy strings and see if it works? I guess some other parts of your code may make some mess. You may also think of using *ListView* instead of old *ListBox*.

Comment: I changed ListBox On ListView but it didn't help. I load data in my constructor. 
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   AllWords.Items.Add(string.Format("{0:00000}", i));
}
That is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found answer on my question. :) Yeeee :)
My mistake was that in mainPage I didn't contained all in the grid.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CommandBar Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <AppBarButton Label="Menu" Click="ToogleMenu_Click">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE700;"/>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back" Click="GoBack_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Home" Label="Play" Click="GoHome_Click"/>
    </CommandBar>
    <SplitView Grid.Row="1" Name="MySplitView"
               DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"
               CompactPaneLength="50"
               OpenPaneLength="200"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <SplitView.Pane >
            <StackPanel>
                <ListBox SelectionMode="Single"
                         Name="ListOfMenu"
                         SelectionChanged="ListOfMenu_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBoxItem Name="LearnWordsItem">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                                       Text="&#xE12B;" 
                                       FontSize="30"
                                       MinWidth="50"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Nauka słówek"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>

                    <ListBoxItem Name="SettingItem">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                                       Text="&#xE115;" 
                                       FontSize="30"
                                       MinWidth="50"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Ustawienia"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>

                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>

        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame Name="MyFrame" >

            </Frame>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>

</Grid>
```

Enough to change StackPanel on Grid. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you've set three `RowDefinition` as "*", it certainly will drive out those buttons. If you want to make these buttons always show there, you need to set fixed height for the two rows. See the following code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Name="WordBeforeTranslation"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="20" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Name="WordAfterTranslation"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="20" />
            <TextBlock Name="WordArticulation"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="20" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2">
            <ListBox Name="AllWords" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="0"
                Content="Previous"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        <Button Grid.Column="1"
                Content="Check"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                Content="Next"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="0"
            Name="BtnLoadFile"

            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Content="Load file" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Content="New Random" />
        <Button Grid.Column="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Content="--------" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is working, but probably you put your grid in the MainPage. My grid is in separate page and I load page with grid to frame which is in SplitView which is in MainPage. And this combination didn't work.

Comment: Look on last code. There I showed my code of main Page.